# UIImage Fill Pattern Color

Tags: swift, image-processing, drawing, core-graphics, flood-fill

For Example, I have the below image used for demo purpose only

[image]

- **Fill close portion with pattern** 
  if user tap on any part of T-Shirt, than T-Shirt should be filled with selected pattern image.

  - I have used to find an array of the point contains close area it takes time as well to find close region points and try to draw color at that points, but it takes too much time to draw because there are many points for the close region.

I have used code from below link
https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill 
This algorithm is actually for flood fill, but I have added one more method to collect all points to one NSSet. 
A help is too much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I have used to find array of point contains close area it take time as well to find close regoin points, and try to draw color at that points, but it take too much time to draw becuase there is many points for close region. "_ If you already made such an effort, you should include your code in the question, so people can help you improve that instead of expecting people to write code from scratch for such a generic problem. In its current state, without any code your question is too broad to be considered on topic here on SO.

Comment: What format do you get the images in?

Comment: @DávidPásztor i have edited the question, it used to scanline fill algorithm, and instead of the actual development of flood fill(Replace color at a point), I have collect all points in NSSet and use that points.

Comment: @hennes I actually use .png format image.